# Passing a 2d array to a method

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
const int width = 100, height = 100;
void clearBoard(bool *board[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    bool gameboard[width][height];
    clearBoard(gameboard);

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}

void clearBoard(bool *board[]){
       for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            board[x][y] = false;
}
```

The error at hand is:

```
C2664: 'void clearBoard(bool *[])' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'bool [100][100]' to 'bool *[]'
```

I think I have the basic understanding of how pointers work, and 2D pointer, but for some reason this won't work. Would love it if someone could explain what I'm getting wrong.

Comment: you should have `bool board[][100]` in the function parameter...

Comment: well that embarrassing, thank you :D

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function

Comment: When arrays decay to pointer, it always decays to 1d pointer `T*` no matter it is a 1d array or 2d. To pass it to the function, use `T[][N]` or `&T[M][N]` (which is more idiomatic in C++). If you insist on passing as pointer, you need to calculate the offset yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing an n-dimensional array as a function argument, you can let only the first dimension be implicit. Please try:

```
void clearBoard(bool board[][height]){
       for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            board[x][y] = false;
}
```

Comment: you should mention the other methods too like pointer to pointer method or array of pointers methods.